# Explain something.logic in javascript?

Tags: javascript, wai-aria, reserved-words

Currently, I am quite new to javascript and I came across one of the javascript keyword (.logic). I tried to googled this keyword, but I couldn't find the answer to it. Can anyone please explain what is the meaning of it? When, why should we use it? It seem like it is create the object in a logical order or something.

Here is the snippet of the code:

```
var checkboxes = slice(document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox'));
  for (var checkbox of checkboxes)
    checkbox.logic = new Checkbox(checkbox);
```

***Note: I tried to learn ARIA right now. that is why I don't use the native checkbox.*

Here is the code for the HTML part:

```
<div class="demo">

  <h2>Custom checkboxes</h2>

  <div tabindex="0" class="checkbox" checked>
    Tim-Tams
  </div>
  <div tabindex="0" class="checkbox">
    Mint slices
  </div>    

</div>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
    function Checkbox(el) {
    this.el = el;

    this.el.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown.bind(this));
    this.el.addEventListener('click', this.toggle.bind(this));

    // Initialize role and aria-checked state.
    this.el.setAttribute('role', 'checkbox');
    if (this.el.hasAttribute('checked')) {
      this.el.setAttribute('aria-checked', 'true');
    } else {
      this.el.setAttribute('aria-checked', 'false');
    }
  }

  Checkbox.prototype.handleKeyDown = function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
      case VK_ENTER:
      case VK_SPACE: {
        this.toggle();
        break;
      }
    }
  };

  Checkbox.prototype.toggle = function() {
    if (this.el.hasAttribute('checked')) {
      this.el.removeAttribute('checked');

      // Keep checked attribute and aria-checked in sync.
      this.el.setAttribute('aria-checked', 'false');
    } else {
      this.el.setAttribute('checked', '');

      // Keep checked attribute and aria-checked in sync.
      this.el.setAttribute('aria-checked', 'true');
    }
  };

  //HERE IS THE QUESTION PART================================
  var checkboxes = slice(document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox'));
  for (var checkbox of checkboxes)
    checkbox.logic = new Checkbox(checkbox);
```

Comment: If you don't understand the code, where did you get it from?

Comment: There's nothing special about the word logic. Looks like you're just storing a reference to the Checkbox there on your DOM element.

Comment: You are setting a property with dot notation. Is that what you are after?

Comment: @Alohci I got the code from udacity.com where they teach Accessibilty.

Comment: @epascarello  the be accurate. I want to know why do we have this:
"checkbox.logic = new Checkbox(checkbox);"   what is the meaning of "logic" here? What is it doing?

Comment: Because the library requires it?  No idea without knowing what the random library you got off the internet is doing.

Comment: @ray can you please collaborate a little more? I am new to programming. Thanks!

Comment: @epascarello hmm...

Comment: They are storing a reference to the element as a property on the input so it can be referenced. That is all that it seems to be doing. So later on you want to reference the code you just select the input `console.log(document.getElementById("someInput").logic);` and now you have reference to the Checkbox code.

Comment: @epascarello OK, thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm pretty junior at prototypal inheritance, so anyone please chime in to verify/clarify my answer.

From what I understand, .logic is not a native JavaScript function or method, rather it is adding a property to an object as part of prototypal inheritance.

What this snippet of code is doing...

```
var checkboxes = slice(document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox'));
for (var checkbox of checkboxes)
checkbox.logic = new Checkbox(checkbox);
```

...is turning the custom html checkboxes into objects objects using the .slice function (these are array-like, so they can turn into objects).

In short, checkbox.logic is similar to....

```
var checkbox = {logic: "doing stuff with the Checkbox class that was called"};
```

Not a perfect metaphor but I hope that clarifies this.